# Spread config files to child poms (maven)

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-exec-plugin

I have a parent pom which is inherited by multiple other poms

```
superpom
|--pokemon
|--|--app
|--|--infrastructure
|--yu-gi-oh
|--|--app
|--|--infrastructure
```

I have multiple config files like:

- a cve-suppress.xml file for the good old dependency plugin (can be directly on pom level)
- logback.xml (must be in test/resources)
- ...

Of course, I could have these files in every project in every module, but changes would lead to changes everywhere and therefore consume much time.

How can I effectively move/copy the files on runtime to the child poms?

Does files are mostly used for **testing in gitlab pipelines**

### Possible ideas

#### 1. Resource Plugin in `superpom`

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resource-one</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/destination-folder</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>source-files</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>foo.txt</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

- superpom specifies path to resource
- **not working**, because when e.g. `pokemon` executes plugin, in this scope, the file does not exist

#### 2. Use Gitlab variables/files

- copy files in gitlab pipelines to desired place
- **problem1** -> copy file to every test/resource folder in every module of project is hard and changes to path may lead to errors
- **problem2** -> file content is in gitlab therefore separeted from parent pom, overview might get blurry

#### 3. Use mojo exec plugin

- trigger script directly creating file
- I am not sure how to do this exactly, I cannot find good examples so far :/

---

Do you have any other ideas? Is there a way I am missing or a dedicated plugon for this?